# About app extension in the safari

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

I customize a share extension, I set it on in the safari, it's showed, but when I open the safari next time, it's not showed in the safari menu and the switch of my share extension is on, why ? who can help me, thanks very much!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: I open the switch, Click 'Done', the 'BddShare' is showed, but when I open safari menu next time, it is not showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in iOS. There is no workaround in the current version. File a bug report with Apple and hope that they fix it soon.

Answer given by @Tom Harrington on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452686/app-is-not-showing-in-the-share-menu-of-shared-options-in-shared-extension-in-io)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved, but I don't understand. I just modify the extension's app id.